# time() and how PHP parses the script

Tags: php

I put `$START_TIME = time();` at the beginning of my code, and `$END_TIME = time();` at the end of my code. then I did `echo ($END_TIME - $START_TIME);` and received a difference of ~ `4`.

My question is, *how inaccurate is this way of measuring parsing/processing time? and why?*

edit: i took out the stupid part of my question :) the rest of the question still stands!

Comment: `time()` measures integer seconds...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`time()` is giving you the seconds since the "unix big bang". What you want is `microtime(true)` ([see documentation here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php)) which gives you the microseconds.

Comment: `microtime(true)` is as accurate as it gets when using PHP ;).

Comment: @light If you use `microtime(true)` it's a good quick and simple approach, yes.

Comment: Thank you both! Sorry for the mishap with the question before!

Comment: Also, `microtime()` gives you microseconds, not milliseconds (that's a thousand times more accurate)

Comment: Thanks @MadaraUchiha - the name of the function already suggests it ;).